# Facebook creates a Business Page for each page on my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm experiencing some issues with my website, regarding to Facebook page's behaviour. I added the opengraphs tags (including an "fb:admins" with my own ID) and now, everytime I click on a Like button on my domain, a new Page is created inside Facebook (i.e. on the http://facebook.com/pages/manage).

Why is this happening? And even more important: how can I make it stop?! I manually created the Page on Facebook for my business, and I don't want any other Page on FB to be created!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the Like button works ; it creates a virtual 'admin' page for each liked URL which is of the appropriate type which allows you to post updates into the news feed of the users who have liked that URL - it also enables access to the insights for the Like button

If you don't want them appearing in the list of adminned pages on your account for some reason, the easiest thing to do is to create an App, and use the App ID as the admin of the pages instead of using your user ID.

Comment: In addition to this, worth noting that **only you** can view these Open Graph pages. There's more documentation about it here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/#admin

Comment: Thanks guys! I will try this approach. Is there any problem if I delete the 'virtual admin' pages that were created? Will I lose the count number of likes displayed on my site?
I don't want to pollute my personal Facebook for my brand...

Comment: Like Matt said, nobody but you will see those pages, but as far as I know deleting the admin page resets the like count - i'm not 100% sure about that though